# PHP - Find value in an array of objects

Tags: php, json, search, multidimensional-array

I am working with a JSON file that is acting as a mini database, it is laid out as such:

```
[
  {
    "id": "someIdentified",
    "name": "someName",
    "files" [
      {"url": "someUrl.ext","urlDescription": "Some Description"},
      {"url": "anotherUrl.ext", "urlDescrition": "Some other Description"}
    ]
  }
  {
    "id": "someIdentified",
    "name": "someName",
    "files" [
      {"url": "someUrl.ext","urlDescription": "Some Description"},
      {"url": "anotherUrl.ext", "urlDescrition": "Some other Description"}
    ]
  }
  {
    "id": "someIdentified",
    "name": "someName",
    "files" [
      {"url": "someUrl.ext","urlDescription": "Some Description"},
      {"url": "anotherUrl.ext", "urlDescrition": "Some other Description"}
    ]
  }
]
```

If I wanted to check if a value existed anywhere in this array of objects, for example does "someName" exist or "someUrl.ext" exist and have it return true or false, how would I do that? I can seem to search one layer deep, but I am not sure how to search deeper... Still very new to PHP, appreciate all the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a recursive search:

```
    function searchValueRecursive($array, $value) {
        if (in_array($value, $array)) {
            return true;
        }

        foreach ($array as $element) {
            if (is_array($element) && $this->searchValueRecursive($element, $value)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

This is the test i did:

```
            $jsonString = <<<heredocstring
[
  {
    "id": "someIdentified",
    "name": "someName",
    "files": [
      {"url": "someUrl.ext","urlDescription": "Some Description"},
      {"url": "anotherUrl.ext", "urlDescrition": "Some other Description"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "someIdentified",
    "name": "someName",
    "files": [
      {"url": "someUrl.ext","urlDescription": "Some Description"},
      {"url": "anotherUrl.ext", "urlDescrition": "Some other Description"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "someIdentified",
    "name": "someName",
    "files": [
      {"url": "someUrl.ext","urlDescription": "Some Description find me"},
      {"url": "anotherUrl.ext", "urlDescrition": "Some other Description"}
    ]
  }
]
heredocstring;

$array = json_decode($jsonString, true); //  pass true to make it an assoc array


            $res = $this->searchValueRecursive($array, 'Some Description find me');
```

Comment: Works fine if it is just nested arrays, but not if it is an array of objects.

Comment: I edited the answer, you can pass true to the JSON decode to make it an associative array